# Is it possible enforce a delay between launching containers in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am following this [docker tutorial](https://docker-curriculum.com/), and am running into trouble with docker compose.
The problem is when I run `docker-compose up`, the web container fails to connect to the es one, and after a few failing retries, it gives up and dies (the web container then exits by itself).

However, from looking at the logs, it seems that this is because the es container is just taking its time getting started - if I then repeat the `docker-compose up` after that (once es is already up and running), the web container works fine.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to specify from within a docker-compose.yml file, a time delay between starting up the containers?

The terminal output where the web container initially fails to connect to es is as follows:

C:\work\docker_learning\FoodTrucks> docker-compose up
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

Starting es ... done
Starting foodtrucks_web_1 ... done
Attaching to es, foodtrucks_web_1
es     | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:43,255][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:43,411][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [_ywWy9B] using [1](https://docker-curriculum.com/) data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sdc)]], net usable_space [230.9gb], net total_space [250.9gb], types [ext4]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:43,412][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [_ywWy9B] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:43,458][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_ywWy9B] node name derived from node ID [_ywWy9B8QZSIn81FhEchNA]; set [node.name] to override
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:43,470][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_ywWy9B] version[6.3.2], pid[1](https://docker-curriculum.com/), build[default/tar/053779d/2018-07-20T05:20:23.451332Z], OS[Linux/4.19.128-microsoft-standard/amd64], JVM["Oracle Corporation"/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/10.0.2/10.0.2+13]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:43,471][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_ywWy9B] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.4LDlDF7A, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,178][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,180][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [analysis-common]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,180][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [ingest-common]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,180][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [lang-expression]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,180][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [lang-mustache]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,181][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [lang-painless]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,182][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [mapper-extras]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,184][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [parent-join]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,189][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [percolator]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,189][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [rank-eval]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,189][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [reindex]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,190][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [repository-url]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,190][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [transport-netty4]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,190][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [tribe]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,190][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-core]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,190][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,190][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,190][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,191][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,191][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,191][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,191][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-security]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,191][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,191][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,191][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,192][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:47,192][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [_ywWy9B] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:52,773][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [_ywWy9B] parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:55,243][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [_ywWy9B] using discovery type [single-node]
web_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/**init**.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.4) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
web_1  |   RequestsDependencyWarning)
web_1  | Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 5 secs...
web_1  | Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 5 secs...
web_1  | Out of retries. Bailing out...
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:57,622][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_ywWy9B] initialized
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:57,623][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_ywWy9B] starting ...
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:57,925][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [_ywWy9B] publish_address {172.26.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:58,004][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [_ywWy9B] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:58,116][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [_ywWy9B] publish_address {172.26.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:58,117][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_ywWy9B] started
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:59,070][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [_ywWy9B] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:59,147][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [_ywWy9B] license [8feb64bb-90d9-4dd7-8c89-a65273596aaa] mode [basic] - valid
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:59,173][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [_ywWy9B] recovered [1](https://docker-curriculum.com/) indices into cluster_state
es     | [2021-04-25T12:39:59,954][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [_ywWy9B] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[sfdata](https://docker-curriculum.com/)] ...]). `

Comment: Not directly in Compose; either set the container to restart until it comes up, or change the container startup to wait for dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

try to add depends_on and health check to docker-compose file

```
services:
    service_1:
       ...
       depends_on: 
          db:
             condition: service_healthy

    service_2:
       healthcheck:
          ...
```

It will enforce containers start order

Also example from docs

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on

UPD

try this

```
es:
  ...
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1"]
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 30s
    retries: 3
```

Comment: ok, I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: currently, web just has `depends on: --es`, as per the tutorial

Comment: @user3801230 only depends on? or with health check? Also, can you provide your docker-compose file?

Comment: with depends_on but no health check, just trying to work out the syntax on how to add health check

Comment: the docker-compose file is the same as the tutorial repo, with just the image name on line 13 substituted for my local one
https://github.com/prakhar1989/FoodTrucks/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: @user3801230 added healthcheck example to answer